# problem with React code in jsfiddle. help me out

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just a beginner to write this code in react.
I think code is ok. or else change it.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

all imported..

```
class Calcul extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
            number1: 0,
            number2: 0,
            total: 0
        };
        this.add= this.add.bind(this);
        this.sub= this.sub.bind(this);
    }
```

bind is also done.

and made functions individually

```
add(){
    a+b javascript code    
}

sub(){
    a-b js code    
}
```

Rendered and called the add function inside.

```
  render() {
    return (
    <div class="calle-add">
     <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click me 

      {this.add()}      
      </div>
   )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Calcul />, document.getElementById("#app"))
```

is this correct way to write code in jsfiddle react. And can v divide the code html different and react code differently

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a closing `</button>` tag in your render method.
Second of all, you shouldn't display `{this.add()}` inside your `<div>`, it's a nonsense, actually.

After all, your `render` should look like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
    <div class="calle-add">
     <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
     <p>SOme additional text you might want to output<p> 
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Also targeting div should be done without `#` sign, like this
`ReactDOM.render(<Calcul />, document.getElementById("app"))`

Moreover, React doesn't require `constructor` anymore to set the initial state, now it can be done as following. And you also can replace `React.Component` with `Component` as you imported `Component` in the 2nd line:

```
class Calcul extends Component {
  state = {
    number1: 0,
    number2: 0,
    total: 0,
  }
}
```

You can also avoid all that confusing binding by creating methods as arrow functions

```
add = () => {your js code}
sub = () => {your js code}
```

and then your button will look like
`<button onClick={this.add}>Click me</button>`